# How to play stream again after stop it in android?

Tags: android

I make one app in android, my problem is that when i play the stream it is playing well but when i click on stop button and then click on play button then song is not playing, how to do that ? please help me if anybody know. below is code that i write :-

```
    // method for play stream after stop it.
public void startradio(View v) {
        try{
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                return;
            }
               mp.start();
        } catch(IllegalStateException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

// method for stop stream.
public void stopradio(View v) {
    if(mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.stop();
    }
    mp.release();
}
```

Comment: you're releasing the stream on stop, dont release it when you hit stop and you should be able to start it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Eluvatar's comment is pretty close but no cigar.

If you do that, your app still would be in the wrong state, and would need to call prepare() before calling start() again. You should look at [the event cycle for MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

In other words a possible change would be

```
// method for play stream after stop it.
public void startradio(View v) {
        try{
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                return;
            }
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch(IllegalStateException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

// method for stop stream.
public void stopradio(View v) {
    if(mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.stop();
    }

}
```